# Typing sounds in entry widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, audio

Is there a way to make sound for each keys typing in an entry widget in tkinter?

Just a sample:

```
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a windows or mac?

Comment: @10Rep i use windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use event binding. Every time a key is pressed, it could play a sample sound.

In this example, it plays a very irritating beep sound. Since you use windows, I am using the `winsound` module.

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import winsound
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
def key_pressed(event):
    print("doing")
    winsound.Beep(1000, 100)

e.bind_all("<Key>", key_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

For non-windows users, you can use the [`playsound`](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) module. TO install it use the following:

> python -m pip install playsound

Make sure to download a short beep sound to use in your program. Also, make sure to place both files in the **same directory**.

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
def key_pressed(event):
    playsound("Recording (52).wav")

e.bind_all("<Key>", key_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but there is dis small lag, like keypress gets registered only after the sound finishes, any way to overcome that?

Comment: @CoolCloud Sadly, no. If I make the time shorter, it will fail to work. Sorry :(

Comment: yes :( but i found a way around using pygame module `pygame.mixer.music.load('file.mp3')` and then `pygame.mixer.music.play()` it fixes the delay

Comment: @CoolCloud Oh yeah, that uses threading. Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html).

Comment: Hi, i know this is after long time, but what is the difference between `bind` and `bind_all` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud `bind` just binds one object to the canvas, whereas `bind_all` binds one object to all other objects and the canvas.

Comment: Actually wts the diff of object and widget here?

Comment: @CoolCloud An object is a rectangle, square, etc. But a widget is like a canvas, frame, etc.

Comment: I know this is from July, but to probably fix that lag `playsound` has a non-blocking flag `playsound("path\to\file.wav", block = False)`.

Comment: @tgikal I tried using that, and maybe it's just my computer but it didn't completely elimenate the lag.

Comment: @tgikal Oh okays, thanks, ill take a look